# How to get the last item price by date

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, firebird, firebird2.5

I have 3 Tables in play:

- OrderHeaders as T_OH (ID, Date),
- OrderDetails as T_OD (ID, OH_ID, Item_Type, Item_Code, Price)
- ItemDetails as T_Item (Item_Type, Item_Code, Item_Name, Item_Barcode)

I need to get all distinct items in T.OD but with the last price by date. The fields with same name between tables are the connections, and in T_OD (OH_ID) is connection with T_OH (ID).

I need to get the last price by Date from T.OH for every distinct item in T_OD.
I got to this code for now:

```
SELECT T_OD.Item_Type, T_OD.Item_Code, T_Item.Item_Name, T_Item.Item_Barcode, T_OD.Price
FROM T_OD
LEFT JOIN T_OH ON T_OD.OH_ID=T_OH.ID
LEFT JOIN T_Item ON T_Item.Item_Type=T_OD.Item_Type AND T_Item.Item_Code=T_OD.Item_Code
ORDER BY T_OH.DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to only need the first two tables to get the most recent price per item.  Unfortunately, I don't think Firebird 2.5 supports window functions, so:

```
select od.item_code, od.price
from t_od od join
     t_oh oh
     on oh.id = od.oh_id
where oh.date = (select max(oh2.date)
                 from t_oh oh2 join
                      t_od od2
                      on oh2.id = od2.oh_id
                 where od2.item_code = od.item_code 
                );
```

Comment: You're right, window functions were introduced in Firebird 3.

Comment: What in case if the item have many unit types, means if the purchase have multi shapes of the same item by quantity (piece, box .. etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this short solution:

```
SELECT item_code, Date, Price 
FROM (SELECT  t_od.*, t_oh.Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_code ORDER By t_oh.Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM t_od inner join t_oh on t_od.oh_id = t_oh.id)x 
WHERE rn = 1
```